# Redraw Table contents Java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, cardlayout

i try to change the contents of a table when i clicked something

This is the button clicked function

```
private void jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    this.refresh();
    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (contentPanel.getLayout());
    cl.show(contentPanel, "card4");

}
```

this is the refresh function

```
 public void refresh(){
    try {
        this.dataBarang = Dbc.readDataBase();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I set the table value in initComponents that netbeans gave me( Inside InitComponents)

```
jTable2.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            this.dataBarang,
            new String [] {
                "No", "No Katalog", "Jenis Tes", "Harga"
            }));
```

what should i do in my refresh function so the value in my table changed dynamically

thx

Comment: This question is a bit unclear. Would you mind rewording it?

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two basic approaches...

### You Could...

Create a new table model and apply it to the table...

This is typically the quickest solution and would allow you to use solutions like `SwingWorker` to build the model in the background before applying to the table

### You Could...

Remove all the rows from the table model and add the new rows as required.

This is more complicated and would require you to complete the update within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Take a look at [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for details and examples